# Updating an indexed view with NOEXPAND

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexed-view

Suppose I have a table `T`, and I have an indexed view `V` on it:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T (id int PRIMARY KEY, b bit NOT NULL, txt varchar(20));
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.V
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
  SELECT T.Id, T.txt
  FROM dbo.T AS T
  WHERE T.b = 1;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_V ON dbo.V (Id);
```

> In this trivial example it's basically just a filtered index, but it could also have joins and such like.

I would now like to select some rows in `T` where `b = 1`, the filtered view here is very useful, and I'm on Standard so have to use `NOEXPAND` (or it's too complex for view matching):

```
SELECT Id, txt
FROM V WITH (NOEXPAND);
```

Now I want to update these rows to some value. The view qualifies as updatable so I can do this:

```
UPDATE V
SET txt = 'Foo';
```

This does not use the indexed view to find the rows to update, even though it needs them to actually update the view. What I would like it to do is use the view like a normal table index, and identify the rows to update from it, pass them to the Clustered Index Update on `T`, followed by an Update on the view. So I try this:

```
UPDATE V WITH (NOEXPAND)
SET txt = 'Foo';
```

This fails with `"Hint 'noexpand' on object 'V' is invalid."`

I know I can get round it with a query such as this:

```
UPDATE T
SET txt = 'Foo'
FROM T
JOIN V WITH (NOEXPAND) ON V.Id = T.Id;
```

But this means an extra Seek. Not only that, it adds a Filter on the subsequent indexed view update to check the rows match the view (a joined view would require the joins to be evaluated) when, clearly, they must match the view.

**Is there any way of getting this to work in the way I would like?**

---

**Update:**

It does not help to put the view in a `FROM` clause, or even in a derived table, a CTE or another view. As soon as it looks to the parser that it's being used for an update, it fails.

There is no indication that `NOEXPAND` should not work either in the [Table Hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15), [Indexed View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15), or [Updatable Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#updatable-views) documentation. The docs for the [`UPDATE` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) specifically mention that certain table hints are not allowed, but only `NOLOCK` and `READUNCOMMITTED` are excluded (recently updated to add `NOEXPAND` but with no explanation)

Comment: ..have you tried joining the view to itself with noexpand ? `update a set txt = '1234' from dbo.V as a join dbo.V as b with(noexpand) on a.id = b.id where b.xyz=.....`

Comment: Self-joining the view is the same result as joining to the table

Comment: For anyone (like /me) who is asking WTF is `WITH (NOEXPAND)`, see [Using WITH (NOEXPAND) to Get Parallelism with Scalar UDFs in Indexed Views](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/using-noexpand-get-parallelism-scalar-udfs-indexed-views/)

Comment: These articles by Paul White are also very relevant: [Indexed Views and Statistics](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/indexed-views-and-statistics) and this one: [Another Reason to Use NOEXPAND hints in Enterprise Edition](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints)